# how to style radio buttons in css?

Tags: css

yo guys, im creating radio buttons like to this one 
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCD3.png)
could you please guide me how to style the radio bottons and how to draw that line that links them. thank you all. this is for my website and i want to do the same work. im finding only this problem thank you again. all suggestions are welcomed

```css
/* background of dog photo */
.sizeVisual-image {
  background-color: #00263e;;
}

/* hover label text */
ul li:hover label {
  color: #f2a900;
}

/* click on the label */
input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  color: #f2a900;
}

/* box horizental*/
.radioGroup {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #00263e
}
```

```html
<body>

<!-- INSERT IMAGE  -->
<div class="sizeVisual-image">
  <img class="img img_larger" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1577/4333/files/Fit-Guide-Measurement-Girth.svg?v=3289972504356902595" width="400" height="300" alt="">
</div>
<!-- END INSERT IMAGE  -->


<!-- creation ratio btn set for size options -->
<fieldset>

  <legend class="isVisuallyHidden">Select Size</legend> <!-- title of the btn set -->
  <ul class="radioGroup radioGroup_scale"> <!--creation of btn list -->

    <!-- CREATION OF XXSMALL btn -->
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="xxsmall" value="XXSmall" class="radio-input isVisuallyHidden js-product-size" checked="">
      <label class="radio radio_size" for="xxsmall">
        <span class="radio-inner_size"><span></span></span>
        <div class="set">
          <div #FF0000class="set-hd">
            <div class="radio-text_size">
              XXSmall
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="set-bd">
            <div class="radio-text_size isHiddenTablet">
              13-17 in (33-43 cm)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <!-- END OF  XXSMALL btn -->

    <!-- CREATION OF XSMALL btn -->
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="xsmall" value="XSmall" class="radio-input isVisuallyHidden js-product-size">
      <label class="radio radio_size" for="xsmall">
        <span class="radio-inner_size"><span></span></span>
        <div class="set">
          <div class="set-hd">
            <div class="radio-text_size">
              XSmall
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="set-bd">
            <div class="radio-text_size isHiddenTablet">
              17-22 in (43-56 cm)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <!-- END OF XSMALL btn -->

    <!-- creation of SMALL btn -->
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="small" value="Small" class="radio-input isVisuallyHidden js-product-size">
      <label class="radio radio_size" for="small">
        <span class="radio-inner_size"><span></span></span>
        <div class="set">
          <div class="set-hd">
            <div class="radio-text_size">
              Small
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="set-bd">
            <div class="radio-text_size isHiddenTablet">
              22-27 in ( 56-69 cm)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <!-- END of SMALL btn -->

    <!-- CREATION OF MEDIUM btn -->
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="medium" value="Medium" class="radio-input isVisuallyHidden js-product-size">
      <label class="radio radio_size" for="medium">
        <span class="radio-inner_size"><span></span></span>
        <div class="set">
          <div class="set-hd">
            <div class="radio-text_size">
              Medium
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="set-bd">
            <div class="radio-text_size isHiddenTablet">
              27-32 in (69-81 cm)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <!-- END OF MEDIUM btn -->

    <!-- CREATION OF XLARGE btn -->
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="large-xlarge" value="Large/XLarge" class="radio-input isVisuallyHidden js-product-size">
      <label class="radio radio_size" for="large-xlarge">
        <span class="radio-inner_size"><span></span></span>
        <div class="set">
          <div class="set-hd">
            <div class="radio-text_size">
              Large/XLarge
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="set-bd">
            <div class="radio-text_size isHiddenTablet">
              32-42 in (81-107 cm)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <!-- END OF XLARGE btn -->
  </ul>
</fieldset>
<!-- end ratio btn set for size options -->

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might wanna check https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407461/why-does-radiobutton-css-styling-behave-opposite-to-checkbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does radiobutton CSS-styling behave opposite to checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407461/why-does-radiobutton-css-styling-behave-opposite-to-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a combination of techniques.
I would recommend placing the input inside the label by the way:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div>{ label stuff }</div>
</label>
```

This will make the markup easier and has some accessibility benefits as well.

From there you can style the radiobutton itself using `:before` and `:after` pseudoclasses as described [here on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

For the line itself, you could use again an `:before` pseudoclass on the label itself with just a background or border, something like this:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label:before {
  border: 2px solid white;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

You would have to calculate the top of course to be nicely in line with the radiobutton.

Note: I might be missing some details, but this should point you the right direction for you to do manage to make it by yourself.

Comment: Very well put together